# Exporting jQuery custom plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I really hope this question doesn't end marked as 'already answered' because I've minutely checked previous questions and my case, unfortunately, doesn't happen to be there.

I've already create a (working) jQuery function to transform a form into a JSON object so I can send it to the server (this is all with an educational purpose by the way, so please save your time before telling me to use a library lol) and even though is working great, I want to save it in a separate file so my main script doesn't look too awful.

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.formToJSON = function(){
        let json = {};
        if($(this).is('form')){
            $.each($(this).find('input'), function(){
                if(this.name && this.value){ //are not empty
                    if(this.type === 'checkbox' && this.checked){
                        json[this.name] = (json[this.name] || []).concat(this.value || ''); //check if exists
                    }else{
                        json[this.name]= this.value;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
    }
})(jQuery);
```

What do I need to do to use it by just importing the script in the HTML file?

The followinglike function patters are not what I'm looking for in my script by the way.

```js
(function($) {

    $.fn.helloWorld = function() {

        return this.each( function() {
            $(this).text("Hello, World!");
        });

    }

}(jQuery));
```

I'd appreciate if someone could help me achieve the goal which is using my script like this (I can already use like that but it needs the function to be in the main script):

```js
$('form').formToJSON();
```

Comment: Why you don't use `serialize`? https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: As I've mentioned before, this is all for educational purpose and serialize doesn't approach the finish I'm looking for.@TanDuong

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just figured out all I need to do is add several declarations of functions inside my IIF (Immediately Invoked Function) jQuery function.

```js
(function($){
 $.fn.logme = function(){
  console.log(this);
 }

 $.fn.logHi = function(){
  console.log('hi!');
 }

})(jQuery)
```